# How can we correctly implement a list of two (calculated) variables?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want to use `foreach` to loop through two variables at the same time, in Tikz.  I'd like to go through the variable `\y` from 0 to 7.  At the same time, I'd like to go through `\yy` from 0 to 14, by increments of 2.  I'd like to know how to do this without writing out the entire list.

For example, the following code works:

```
 \foreach \y / \yy in {0/0, 1/2, 2/4, 3/6, 4/8, 5/10, 6/12, 7/14}
   \node at (0,\y) {\y -- \yy};
```

But I can't seem to get this code to work:

```
 \foreach \y / \yy in {0/0, 1/2, ..., 7/14}
   \node at (0,\y) {\y -- \yy};
```

I'm planning on using **LOTS** of loops like this, so I'm really trying to figure out how to get a double loop with the dots to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not using a single variable and `evaluate`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yy using int(2*\y)] in {0,...,7}
   \node at (0,\y) {\y -- \yy};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Evaluate, from what I've seen, gives values like 2.0 and 4.0.  I just want the integer value.  But thanks for the idea, +1 for you!  By the way, is there a way to get evaluate to give integer values?

Comment: @MattGroff Of course, you can truncate the value.

Comment: @MattGroff: `int(2*\y)`

Comment: @MattGroff as Heiko said in his comment, or with `\pgfmathroundto`.

Answer (score 2):

Possible also

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y in {0,...,7}
{ \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yy}{2*\y}
   \node  at (0,\y) {\y -- \yy};
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun with `fp`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido,fp}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+1}{10}{\FPeval\temp{round(sin(\i):6)} $(\i,\temp)$\endgraf}
\end{document}
```

[image]